# Simple probability question, with faulty screws.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, percentages

I have translated the problem as follows:

> A factory produces screws, the probability of them being faulty is 0.01 independently. The factory makes a box with 10 screws and recalls the boxes containing 2 or more faulty screws. What is the percentage of boxes that the factory has to recall?

Comment: I think you've done it right. Is the book giving you $18\%$ or $.18\%$? Just thinking about it with common sense, $18\%$ seems really high (and as you've shown, the probability the box will be perfect is already $>90\%$)

Comment: Seems to me also that your calculation is right. Cannot find what the solution given in the book might refer to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is:
The percentage of faulty boxes is equal to the probability of faulty boxes.
In order to make easy my calculation, I calculate the probability of the boxes which have no faulty screws or have at least one faulty screw. Then I can find the probability I am searching for as follows:
$$S_{FaultyBox} = 1 - S_{NonFaultyBox}$$
To find the Non-Faulty Box I first find the probability that no box has faulty screws and then I sum to it the probability that it has only one faulty screw as follows:
$$S_{NoFaultyScrew} = (1-0.01)^{10}=0.904382$$
(Because they are independent of each other)
$$S_{OneFaultyScrew}= \binom{10}{1}0.01^{1}(1-0.01)^{9}=0.091351$$
(Using Bernoulli trials).
$$S_{NonfaultyBox} = S_{NofaultyScrew} + S_{OneFaultyScrew} = 0.995733$$
Finally, I find the probability that I was searching for:
$$S_{FaultyBox} = 1 - 0.995733 = 0.004267 \Rightarrow 0.4267\%$$

Answer (score 0):

No faulty: $\big(\frac{9.99}{10}\big)^{10} = 0.9900\ldots$

$1$ faulty: $\big(\frac{9.9}{10}\big)^9\times \frac{0.01}{10}=0.0010\ldots$

So the probability is $\approx 0.9$%.

Comment: Did you know: @abc...'s real name is Harry.

Comment: What? I don't understand.....

Comment: @abc... Your calculation for 1 faulty screw is wrong